# Android - Real Time Chat App Using Firebase

Tags: java, android, sqlite, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm building an real time chat app based on firebase Database
so my problem that each time the apps call the oncreat methods i call my displaychatmessages() method the problem that all the messages in my DB where displayed on my listview.
my question that can the app face some problems when the database become bigger ?? after some monthes or years ?? i mean that it will handel alot of data at the start time

as a solution i'm trying to store old messages localy and load them later and the app will load only new added childs ? but i dont know how to start this if it's a good idea can some one help me ?

**my old displayChatMessages method :**
any ideas about a new one ??

```
private void displayChatMessages() {

    RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.myRv);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutmang = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutmang.setStackFromEnd(true);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutmang);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
            ChatMessage.class, R.layout.activity_main, RecyclerView.ViewHolder.class, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final ChatMessage user,
                                          final int position) {


            int y=0;
            ChatMessage user2;
            if (position>1){
                user2 = getItem(position - 1);
            }else{
                user2 = getItem(position );
            }

            ChatMessage ori2 = getItem(position );
            if (user.getMessageUser().matches(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail())) {
                    if (user2.getMessageFULL()<ori2.getMessageFULL()){
                    y=1;
                    populateType1((HolderMe) viewHolder, user,  1);
                }else{
                    populateType1((HolderMe) viewHolder, user, 0);
                }

            }else if (!user.getMessageUser().matches(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail())){
               if (user2.getMessageFULL()<ori2.getMessageFULL()){
                    populateType2((HolderYou) viewHolder, user, 1,FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                }else{
                    populateType2((HolderYou) viewHolder, user, 0,FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                }

            }
            if(user.getMessageTime()< new Date().getTime()) {
                HolderDate vh3 = (HolderDate) viewHolder;
                populateType3(vh3, user, position);
            }
        }

            @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Log.e("ViewT",viewType+"");
            if (viewType == 1) {
                 View userType1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout_holder_me, parent, false);
                return new HolderMe(userType1);
            } else{
               View userType2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.layout_holder_you, parent, false);
                return new HolderYou(userType2);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
              ChatMessage user = getItem(position);
            String s = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
            if (s.equals(user.getMessageUser())) {
             return 1;
            } else {
                 return 2;
            }

        }

        private void populateType1(HolderMe v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            v.getTimeView().setText(DateFormat.format("HH:mm",model.getMessageTime()));
            if (position==1) {
                v.getFullDateView().setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", model.getMessageTime()));
                v.getFullDateView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
                v.getTextv().setText(model.getMessageText());
        }
        private void populateType3(HolderDate vcv, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            vcv.getDate().setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy",model.getMessageTime()));
        }
        private void toaa1( String text) {
            Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        private void  populateType2(HolderYou vv, ChatMessage model, int position,String username) {
            vv.getTimeView().setText(DateFormat.format("HH:mm",model.getMessageTime()));
            if (position==1) {
                vv.getFullDateView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                vv.getFullDateView().setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", model.getMessageTime()));
            }
            vv.getTextv().setText(model.getMessageText());
           if (username.matches("test2@test2.com")) {
                vv.getImageView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.userm);
            } else {
                vv.getImageView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.usera);
                }
        }

    };
    recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing all messages in a chat app is indeed going to cause problems as the number of messages grows. Instead you can use a Firebase Database query to only show the most recent message. For example:

```
DatabaseReference messages = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query recent = messages.orderByKey().limitToLast(100);
```

And then use that in your adapter:

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
        ChatMessage.class, 
        R.layout.activity_main,
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder.class, 
        recent) {
```

Comment: thanks alot it works also i have created a solution everday a new child added and all messages will go there and each time the user tap the loaad more message the app loads the messages of day -i when i increase each time i click load more !! wich is the best solution please ??